# rango de fechas datepicker c#

Tags: c#, mvc

Tengo un problema, necesito filtrar dos fechas de una tabla de la base de datos y no he podido, a ver si me pueden orientar, es en c#, mi controlador

```
public ActionResult Report(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
    {
        using (var db = new bd_sistema_SPEC_adminEntities1())
        { 
            int t = db.mae_plantilla_maquina.Where(i => i.mpm_fecha_creacion>= start && i.mpm_fecha_modificacion <= end).Count();
        int r = db.mae_plantilla_maquina.Count(i => i.mpm_fecha_creacion != null && i.mpm_fecha_creacion >= start && i.mpm_fecha_modificacion <= end);
        ViewBag.EndDate = end;
        ViewBag.StartDate = start;
        ViewBag.Total = t;
        ViewBag.Read = r;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Resulta que en la vista, no he podido definir para que pueda probar el codigo, soy pesimo, a ver si me podrian ayudar, muchas gracias:

querria si se pudiera una vista asi:

[mvc search filter records between two dates stored procedure c#4.6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pPcP9i_YFg)

saludos

Answer (score 1):

Deberías intentas poner la sentencia `BETWEEN` en vez de `=>` que en realidad es `>=`.

Te dejo tu linea de código modificada, esperando te ayude.

```
int t = db.mae_plantilla_maquina.Where(i >= i.mpm_fecha_creacion between start && i.mpm_fecha_modificacion between end).Count();
```

Comment: Gracias, probare!